# How does the $10^{j+1}-1$ to $10^{j}-1+9\cdot10^j$ conversion work?

Tags: induction

We have an assumption $9|10^j-1$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$  (inductive assumption)

At this point the transformation occurs:

$10^{j+1}-1=10^j\cdot10-1=10^{j}-1+9\cdot10^j$ from where we know: $9|10^{j+1}-1$

I would like to ask you to explain how we pass from one form to another and how we get $9|10^{j+1}-1$ from the final transformation.I understand the transition from the first form to the second because $10^{j+1}=10^j\cdot10$, which is obvious thanks to the rules of operations on powers, but I cannot understand the next two steps despite sitting on it for a long time.

Comment: Note that $10=1+9$; also, if $9\mid a$, then $9\mid a+9b$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think I got this: $10^j\cdot10-1=10^j\cdot(9+1)-1=9\cdot10^j+10^j-1$

Comment: I think you’ve got it